# iPhone app to get RSS push notifications (http://192.168.1.xx/rss/feed)

Tags: rss, iphone-app, wifi, lan

I'm looking for an app that can send me push notifications on the update of an XML file on my local webserver via Wi-Fi.

(This info might be irrelevant: I've created this XML output via PHP+MySQL for displaying notifications when any data is entered into the SQL table of my local XAMPP server.)

I've tried apps for both Android and iOS 7, and none of these apps are notifying of additions to the SQL table. The RSS generated at the URL `http://192.168.1.xx/rss/feed.xml` is showing the updated content, but there's no notification to the smartphones.

However, [the portable Windows app *Feed Notifier*](http://www.feednotifier.com/download/) is displaying the RSS notifications within the set interval of 1 minute perfectly! So, I'm sure that my XML is not corrupt, and the data can be passed to the reader as an XML RSS feed.

Also, I think that all the free RSS readers I've tested are submitting my LAN-based URL to their online database and trying to access that XML for updates. And since my local webserver is not accessible over Internet, these apps are not notifying me of any updates on my smartphones.

Hence, I'm looking for a free or paid app for iPhone, that can send push notifications for a RSS feed that's only available over Wi-Fi.